# node.js stream pipeline separately over all files in folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, java-stream, pipeline

I wrote a pipeline that reads an input stream from a file, transforms it and streams it out to an output file. The pipeline works well for one file. Now I want to iterate through all files in a folder, producing a *separate* output file for each input file.

I am completely new to JS and synchronous streams. Did my best to figure it out. However, given n input files, what I currently get is n copies processed from the last input file.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const pipeline = require("stream");

async function processFolder(inPath, outPath) {
  const dir = await fs.promises.opendir(inPath)
  for await (const dirent of dir) {

    let inFile = inPath.concat(dirent.name);
    let outFile = outPath.concat(dirent.name.slice(0,-4), ".json");
  
    console.log(inFile);
    
    await pipeline(
      fs.createReadStream(inFile).setEncoding('utf8'),
      transform,
      fs.createWriteStream(outFile),
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Pipeline failed', err);
        } else {
          console.log('Pipeline succeeded');
        }
      }
    ); 
  }
}

processFolder(inPath, outPath);
```

How can I change the code above so that it processes all files in the directory?
Thank you!